# Serialize iterator object to be passed between processes in Python

Tags: python, matrix, pickle, multiprocess

I have a python script that calculates the eigenvalues of matrices from a list, and I would like to insert these eigenvalues into another collection in the same order as the original matrix and I would like to do this by spawning up multiple processes.

Here is my code:

```
import time
import collections
import numpy as NP
from scipy import linalg as LA

from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def computeEigenV(unit_of_work):
    current_index = unit_of_work[0]
    current_matrix = unit_of_work[1]

    e_vals, e_vecs = LA.eig(current_matrix)
    finished_unit = (current_index, lowEV[::-1])
    return finished_unit

def run(work_list):
    pool = Parallel( n_jobs = -1, verbose = 1, pre_dispatch = 'all')
    results = pool(delayed(computeEigenV)(unit_of_work) for unit_of_work in work_list)
return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create original array of matrices
    original_matrix_list = []
    work_list = []

    #basic set up so we can run this test
    for i in range(0, 100):
        # generate the matrix & unit or work
        matrix = NP.random.random_integers(0, 100, (500, 500))
        #insert into respective resources
        original_matrix_list.append(matrix)

    for i, matrix in enumerate(original_matrix_list):
        unit_of_work = [i, matrix]
        work_list.append(unit_of_work)

    work_result = run(work_list)
```

so `work_result` should hold all the eigenvalues from each matrix after all processes finish. And the iterator I am using is `unit_of_work` which is a list containing the index of the matrix (from the `original_matrix_list`) and the matrix itself.

The weird thing is, if I were to run this code by doing `python matrix.py` everything works perfectly. But when I use [auto](http://cmvl.cs.concordia.ca/auto/) (a program that does calculations for differential equations?) to run my script, typing `auto matrix.py` gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matrix.py", line 50, in <module>
    work_result = run(work_list)
  File "matrix.py", line 27, in run
    results = pool(delayed(computeEigenV)(unit_of_work) for unit_of_work in work_list)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 805, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 658, in dispatch_one_batch
    tasks = BatchedCalls(itertools.islice(iterator, batch_size))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.items = list(iterator_slice)
  File "matrix.py", line 27, in <genexpr>
    results = pool(delayed(computeEigenV)(unit_of_work) for unit_of_work in work_list)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 162, in delayed
    pickle.dumps(function)
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
```

*Note:* when I ran this with `auto` I had to change `if __name__ == '__main__':` to `if __name__ == '__builtin__':`

I looked up this error and it seems like I am not serializing the iterator `unit_of_work` correctly when passing it around to different processes. I have then tried to use `serialized_unit_of_work = pickle.dumps(unit_of_work)`, pass that around, and do `pickle.loads` when I need to use the iterator, but I still get the same error.

Can someone please help point me in the right direction as to how I can fix this? I hesitate to use `pickle.dump(obj, file[, protocol])` because eventually I will be running this to calculate eigenvalues of thousands of matrices and I don't really want to create that many files to store the serialized iterator if possible.

Thanks!! :)

Answer (score -1):

You can't pickle an iterator in `python2.7` (but you can from `3.4` onward).

Also, pickling works differently in `__main__` is different than when not in `__main__`, and it would seem that `auto` is doing something odd with `__main__`.  What you often will observe when pickling fails on a particular object is that if instead of running the script with the object in it directly, you run a script as main which imports the portion of the script with the "difficult-to-serialize" object, then pickling will succeed.  This is because the object will pickle by reference at a namespace level above where the "difficult" object lives… thus it's never directly pickled.

So, you can probably get away with pickling what you want, by adding a reference layer… a file import or a class.  But, if you want to pickle an iterator, you are out of luck unless you move to at least `python3.4`.